# Django admin page looks primitive

Tags: django, django-admin

for reference: i am learning django from this page:- https://www.w3schools.com/django/django_admin.php

im using virtual environment and running this on a local machine: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/

[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffmNi.png)
[Reality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62i9j.png)

please help.
i have tried asking in subreddit and discord but im not yet able to find a fix.
any help is appreciated

Comment: You likely need to add static and media URLs...

Comment: how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Likely that is because static files do not load, like the CSS and JavaScript files. These determine the styling of the page.

You can add a handler to serve static and media files in the *root* `urls.py` with:

```
# proj_name/urls.py

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = (
    [
        # …
    ]
    + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
)
```

Beware that this will *not* work in production (`DEBUG = False`), this means that you will need to configure the web server like Nginx or Apache to serve the static and media files.

Comment: what does "root" urls.py mean?
also do i need to add the plus sign like you did?
thanks for answering.

Comment: lol i changed debug to true, and nothing else. and it worked

Comment: @SatvikRajesh: that's likely because the root url already has paths for the static and media files, so if you later deploy the server, the only thing left is handling the requests through the web server (config)